# Node.js deploy on Heroku fail : TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

Does anyone know what the error means?
I have my app on Node.js and my database on Atlas. When I try to deploy it on Heroku I get this error message in the logs :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null    at
>   parseSrvConnectionString
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:40:23)    at
>   parseConnectionString
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:556:12)    at
>   connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:272:3)
>   at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:218:5    at
>   maybePromise (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:719:3)    at
>   MongoClient.connect
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:214:10)    at
>   Function.MongoClient.connect
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:432:22)    at
>   Database.connect (/app/database.js:9:15)    at Object.
>   (/app/database.js:21:4)    at Module._compile
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)    [31m[nodemon] app crashed
>   - waiting for file changes before starting...[39m

Database.js

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient; require('dotenv').config()

class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.client = null;
    }
    connect() {
        mongo.connect(process.env.URL_DATABASE, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
            if (err) throw err
            this.client = client;

        });
    } }




const db = new Database(); db.connect(); console.log(db); module.exports = db;
```

router.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();
const db = require('./database');
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

// GET ALL

router.get('/books', (req, res, next) => {

    const localdb = db.client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
    const collection = localdb.collection(process.env.COLL_BOOKS);
    collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status(200).send(docs);
    });
});

// GET ONE

router.get('/books/:name', (req, res, next) => {
    let name = req.params.name
    const localdb = db.client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
    const collection = localdb.collection(process.env.COLL_BOOKS);
    collection.findOne({ "name": name }, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status(200).send(docs);
    });
});

// POST ONE

router.post('/books', (req, res, next) => {
    const localdb = db.client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
    const collection = localdb.collection(process.env.COLL_BOOKS);
    let newBook = req.body;
    collection.insertOne(newBook, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status(201).send(true);

    });
});

// DELETE ONE

router.delete('/books/:name', (req, res, next) => {
    const localdb = db.client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
    const collection = localdb.collection(process.env.COLL_BOOKS);
    collection.deleteOne({ "name": req.params.name }, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status(200).send(true)

    })
});

// PUT ONE

router.put('/books/:name', (req, res, next) => {
    const localdb = db.client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
    const collection = localdb.collection(process.env.COLL_BOOKS);
    collection.updateOne({  "name": req.params.name }, { $set: req.body }, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status(201).send(true);
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
    const express = require('express'),
        app = express();
    os = require('os');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const router = require('./router.js')
    require('dotenv').config()


    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use('/api/v1', router);

    const port = (process.env.PORT || '3001');

let server = app.listen(port, os.hostname(), () => {
    let host = server.address().address,
        port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide snippet of your code?? ( /app/database )

Comment: I still can't solve the problem. If anyone has a suggestion to make it work

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and solved it by not storing the complete string of the **mongo Uri** in the .env file.
instead, I only Stored the user and the password

**./config.env**

```
DB_USER=youruser
DB_PASS=yourpassword
```

**./app.js**

```js
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.pm4ek.gcp.mongodb.net/CommentsDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority`)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense dude and got an error

Answer (score 0):

The error goes when I remove the quotes from the DB_URL in Heroku var config, but now it brings me an other error, which is :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of null 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450337+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/router.js:12:31 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450355+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450356+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13) 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450356+00:00 app[web.1]: at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3) 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450357+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450358+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450359+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450359+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.handle (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3) 2020-05-05T10:21:40.450359+00:00 app[web.1]: at router (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12) 2020-05-05T10:21:57.090036+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:725 2020-05-05T10:21:57.090047+00:00 app[web.1]: throw error; 2020-05-05T10:21:57.090048+00:00 app[web.1]: ^ 2020-05-05T10:21:57.090048+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed quotes from docker-compose yml file and it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-mongo-url-error-cannot-read-property-split-of-null/50563/2) link helped me to solve the error.

TLDR; You should remove double quote on your mongo URI config var